# Google Storage + JQuery-File-Upload + Django + Signed URL, how should I change submit() and relevant options?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, jquery-file-upload

I have the following js code and it uses the signed-url api to get signed urls for uploading content to google storage via Django api.

When I use it with the following code :

```
xhr.open("PUT", data.signed_url); 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type); 
xhr.send(file);
```

It works fine and I am able to upload to Google Storage very large files. But obviously, when I do that, I cannot use any progress-bar features of jquery-file-upload.

Can you please suggest on how I should alter the data.submit(), where shall I put it, and how should I change the options or settings prior to submitting. Should I be overriding add or submit callback ?

I feel that there is a missing support for Google Storage with Jquery-file-upload as the only example covers only obsolute Google Blobstore in the following link : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
dataType: 'json',
type: 'PUT',
sequentialUploads: true,

submit: function(e, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
        // pack our data to get signature url
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('filename', file.name);
        formData.append('type', file.type);
        formData.append('size', file.size);

        // Step 3: get our signature URL
        $.ajax({
            url:  '/api/getsignedurl/',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
            },
            primary_data: data,
            data: formData
        }).done(function (data) {
            // Step 5: got our url, push to GCS
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
                console.log("With credentials");
                xhr.open("PUT", data.signed_url, true);
            }
            else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== 'undefined') {
                console.log("With domainrequest");
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open("PUT", data.signed_url);
            }
            else {
                console.log("With null");
                xhr = null;
            }

            //What shall I do to make the following work for uploading GS
            this.primary_data.url = data.signed_url;
            this.primary_data.headers={'Content-Type': file.type};
            this.primary_data.submit();

            xhr.onload = () => {
                const status = xhr.status;
                if (status === 200) {

                } else {
                    alert("Failed to upload 1: " + status);
                }
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
                alert("Failed to upload 2");
            };
            //When the code below uncommented, it uploads to GS succesfully.
            //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
            //xhr.send(file);
        });
    });
},
```

Also this is my cors setup for the GS Bucket.

```
 [
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    "method": ["GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 60
  }
]
```

Comment: hey @UtkuBulkan , can you please clarify on the issue here. As I see from your code you are being able to upload to Cloud Storage successfully? I found also [this example](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload) does it help you?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi, yes now I am able to upload to Google Storage from the browser directly. Thanks.